# Absolute positioning divs in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position

I'm developing a calendar component for Angular and I need to position some div element (representing events) in a grid.

```
this.days.forEach((day: SchedulerViewDay, dayIndex: number) => {
        day.events = this.getEventsInPeriod({...}).map((event: CalendarSchedulerEvent) => {
            const segmentDuration: number = 60.0 / this.hourSegments;
            const dayStartDate: Date =
                setSeconds(setMinutes(setHours(
                setDate(setMonth(setYear(new Date(), day.date.getFullYear()), day.date.getMonth()), day.date.getDate()), this.dayStartHour), this.dayStartMinute), 0);
            const segmentsNumber: number = (differenceInMinutes(event.start, dayStartDate) / segmentDuration);

            return <CalendarSchedulerEvent>{
                ...
                height: this.hourSegmentHeight * (differenceInMinutes(event.end, event.start) / segmentDuration),
                top: (this.hourSegmentHeight * segmentsNumber)
            };
        });
```

With that code, this is the result: 
[image]

As you can see the event div is not correctly positioned. I think that this is due to the grid cell borders so i've applied that fix:

```
top: (this.hourSegmentHeight * segmentsNumber) + (segmentsNumber / 2) // 1px for each separator line
```

Each border is 1px width and I consider only solid borders and not dashed ones (this is the motivation of `/ 2`.

This almost resolve the problem. There's still a misalignment.
Moreover this is not an elegant solution but I can't figure out to make it more clean.

How can I correctly position these divs?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT: implementation of *inorganik*'s solution (first answer)**

I've created the following `mixins` in my `scss` file:

```
@mixin day-x($attr, $attr-count: 7, $attr-steps: 1, $unit: '%') {
    $attr-list: null;

    @for $i from 1 through $attr-count {
        $attr-value: $attr-steps * $i;

        &.day#{$i} {
            #{$attr}: #{$attr-value}#{$unit};
        }

        $attr-list: append($attr-list, unquote(".#{$attr}-#{$attr-value}"), comma);
    }

    #{$attr-list} {
        //append style to all classes
    }
}

@mixin time-x($attr, $start-hour: 0, $end-hour: 23, $attr-steps: 2, $minutes-steps: 15, $unit: '%') {
    $attr-list: null;
    $hours: $start-hour;
    $minutes: 0;
    $attr-count: ((($end-hour + 1) - $start-hour) * 60) / $minutes-steps;

    @for $i from 0 through $attr-count {
        $attr-value: $attr-steps * $i;

        @if($i > 0) {
            $minutes: $minutes + $minutes-steps;
            @if($minutes == 60) {
                $minutes: 0;
                $hours: $hours + 1;
            }
        }

        $hoursString: '#{$hours}';
        @if($hours < 10) {
            $hoursString: '0#{$hours}';
        }

        $minutesString: '#{$minutes}';
        @if($minutes < 10) {
            $minutesString: '0#{$minutes}';
        }

        &.time#{$hoursString}#{$minutesString} {
            #{$attr}: #{$attr-value}#{$unit};
        }

        $attr-list: append($attr-list, unquote(".#{$attr}-#{$attr-value}"), comma);
    }

    #{$attr-list} {
        //append style to all classes
    }
}

@mixin length-x($attr, $attr-steps: 2, $minutes-steps: 15, $unit: '%') {
    $attr-list: null;
    $attr-count: 24 * 60 / $minutes-steps;

    @for $i from 0 through $attr-count {
        $attr-name: $minutes-steps * $i;
        $attr-value: $attr-steps * $i;

        &.length#{$attr-name} {
            #{$attr}: #{$attr-value}#{$unit};
        }

        $attr-list: append($attr-list, unquote(".#{$attr}-#{$attr-value}"), comma);
    }

    #{$attr-list} {
        //append style to all classes
    }
}

@include day-x('left', 7, 5);
@include time-x('top', 6, 22, 1.47);
@include length-x('height', 1.47);
```

Then I apply these styles with `[ngClass]` attribute, calling the following method (I don't need getDay, for now):

```
getPositioningClasses(event: CalendarSchedulerEvent): string {
    const classes: string[] = [
        this.getDayClass(event.start),
        this.getTimeClass(event.start),
        this.getLengthClass(differenceInMinutes(event.end, event.start))
    ];
    return classes.join(' ');
}

private getDayClass(date: Date): string {
    return '';
}
private getTimeClass(date: Date): string {
    let hours: string = date.getHours() < 10 ? `0${date.getHours()}` : `${date.getHours()}`;
    let minutes: string = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? `0${date.getMinutes()}` : `${date.getMinutes()}`;
    return `time${hours}${minutes}`;
}
private getLengthClass(durationInMinutes: number): string {
    return `length${durationInMinutes}`;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Graphically it works like a charm but I need to keep segments height (`58px`) aligned to the percentage increment used to generate positioning classes (now it's `1.47%`).

Is there a way to make those variables (segments height and percentage height and top position increments) from Angular code, making the segment height configurable by the user and let these increments to adapt itself?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT 2: another problem**

Hi again! I've encountered another problem. 
The component hour range it is not fixed but it is configurable from outside.
In the example in the question is 6AM - 22PM. For that range the percentage of 1.47 is fine but if I change the range (eg. 0AM - 22AM) the calendar height is higher and the percentage is not ok anymore.

I think I need to calculate those positioning values from Typescript. But I can't figure out how to do that.

To try something I'm trying this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.calendarContainerHeight = this.calendarContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    const segmentPercentage: number = 100.0 * this.hourSegmentHeight / this.calendarContainerHeight;
    console.log("calendarContainerHeight: ", this.calendarContainerHeight);
    console.log("segmentPercentage: ", segmentPercentage);

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.view.days.forEach(d => {
            d.events.forEach((event: CalendarSchedulerEvent) => {
                let hours: number = event.start.getHours();
                if (this.dayStartHour > 0) { hours = hours - this.dayStartHour; }

                const numberOfSegments: number = hours * this.hourSegments;
                event.top = numberOfSegments * segmentPercentage;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then I've added `[style.top.%]="event.top"` to the event div. This is the result (ignore height for now, I've not managed them yet):

[image]

As you can see the percentage is not accurate and those events which are in the middle of the day (or towards the end of the day) are not positioned correctly.

How could I solve this problem?
Thank you very much, again!

Comment: Great work implementing my solution! Trying to align elements that are sized with different units (% and px) is almost always impossible in CSS. I would recommend that you use percentages for everything, including heights, that way it's completely fluid. Another option is to use a good 'ole <table> with rowspans and colspans. Tables are underrated and are built to display things exactly like what you have. I hope this helps.

Comment: @inorganik I've added an "edit 2" section to my question. Could you take it a look? I'm facing a problem that I can't figure out how to solve. Thank you very much!

Comment: If the component range is not fixed, perhaps you can calculate the top distance of the event not by the time of day but how many hours after the first time on the calendar it starts - in your screenshot it looks like 10:30, so an event starting at 1pm would be 2.5 hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a brittle solution to calculate pixel distances in code. I would use CSS classes. You can have an SCSS mixin generate all the possible classes for you for days, times and segment lengths. Make 3 methods that return css class strings, one for day, one for time, and one for segment length which you can apply with `[ngClass]`. Then a method which calls each one, something like below. This assumes you have an array of segments which store date/time/length info on them:

```
getPositioningClasses(segment: any): string {
  const classes = [this.getDayClass(segment.dayStartDate), this.getTimeClass(segment.dayStartDate), this.getLengthClass(segment.timeLength)];
  return classes.join(' ');
}
```

So your markup might end up looking like this:

```
<segment [ngClass]="getPositioningClasses(segment)"></segment>
```

Compiled:

```
<segment class="day0 time1430 length130"></segment>
```

- `day0` - you could have 0-X for however many days you display. This class is just responsible for distance from the left. Use percentages if you can so that the layout can be flexible.
- `time1430` in this case 2:30pm - This class is just responsible for distance from the top
- `length130` in this case an hour and a half. Ideally set the smallest increment of time (15m?) as a percentage height, then let the mixin multiply the increment for each possible length.

Also to make sure you don't have to factor in borders, put the `box-sizing: border-box` css rule on pretty much everything.

Comment: I've never used mixins in that way. Could you provide a more complete example? (maybe on an online code editor, if you can)

Comment: I've edited my question. Could you take it a look? :)

Comment: I've added an "edit 2" section to my question. Could you take it a look? I'm facing a problem that I can't figure out how to solve. Thank you very much!